# iOs5: NSInvalidArgumentException when creating NSManagedObject from URI representation

Tags: iphone, ios5, nsmanagedobject

I just installed iOs5, and almost all went surprisingly fluent - but now I have a weird problem:

My App writes Object Ids of **NSManagedObjects** to a text file, and then reads them again and re-instantiates the corresponding objects from the persistent store. It worked fine before the update, and now when I call

`[persistentStoreCoordinator managedObjectIdForURIRepresentation:[NSURL URLWithString:objectIdString]]`

I get an **NSInvalidArgumentException - The specified URI is not in the proper scheme**

Googling that specific reason for an invalid argument exception delivers nothing at all, and the object id is exactly what the call to

`[[objectId URIRepresentation]absoluteString]`

returns. And according to the apple documentation the call to *managedObjectIdForURIRepresentation* should not even raise an **NSInvalidArgumentException**, but just return **nil** in case something is wrong ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found it myself.

For anyone with a similar problem: The main problem was not the managedObjectIdForURIRepresentation call, but the objectIdString that came in - although the InvalidArgumentException should not be thrown by the function call IMHO, as it's not stated in the docs.

The actual problem is even more strange: The **objectIdString** comes from an URL that I get by using a URL scheme that calls my application's

`(BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL*)url`

function. The URL scheme entry that is clicked has the right format, like

`appname://x-coredata://objectid`

**BUT**: What I really do get in the **handleOpenURL** function is this:

`appname://x-coredata//objectid`

which is clearly **missing an important detail: the colon after x-coredata!!!** And that is causing the crash ... seems like a bug in handleOpenURL to me ...

Anyway, the workaround for now is to see whether this colon is missing, and then adding it - all works fine then. Going to file a bug report with Apple.